# Is it possible to launch remote file in native application without manual interaction

Tags: javascript, swift, macos, storage, safari-extension

We can accesss the remote files via SMB protocol

> Finder Menu > Go > Connect to server.

ex: smb:///cifsshare/master.tif"

But when we push the command, we only end up to opening the enclosing directory and not to the tif file. Now if i need to open the master.tif file i need to double click and open it. But for the connection i entered address of the file.

Iam trying to achieve same functionality with **safari extension**.

> NSWorkspace.

```
if let url = URL(string: path) {
    if NSWorkspace.shared.open(url) {
       print("Url is opened")
    }
}
```

Result: Same :(

> When tried with Process()

```
//1
let toolPath = "/usr/bin/open"
let arguments = [pathUrl.absoluteString]
     
//2
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = toolPath
task.arguments = arguments
     
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Result: Not Working :(

Is it even possible in macos?
Any clue how to achieve this, is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a two step process:

1. Mount the SMB share to a local mount point
2. Open the file within that mount mount.
3. Unmount the SMB share when you're done with it.

I couldn't find a way to do #1 in a predictable manner. I.e., if something was already mounted at `/Volumes/cifsshare`, then opening `smb:///cifsshare` would automatically mount it to a new folder (`/Volumes/cifsshare (1)`, if I recall correctly), without giving you feedback as to where exactly it ended up.

At a glance, it looks like the APIs that Finder uses to mount SMB reside within [private frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/84509), so there doesn't to be a nice easy API like `SMB.mount(smbURL, to: mountPoint)`.

You can try using the Process API to call `mount_smbfs` (which is just a wrapper around `mount -t smbfs`). You can use it to mount your SMB share to a mount point of your own choosing, like `/Volumes/MyAppSMBShare` or whatever.

From there, you can open the file as normal:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLFromPath: "/Volumes/MyAppSMBShare/master.tif))
```

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts.  But, the mount and the opening of the file cannot be in the two step process. We have a requirement that the file should be open once i pass the Open command with the url. But it only leads to the directory and not opening the file.

Comment: Well that doesn’t seem possible, so clearly you’re going to need a workaround.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your thought. But, is there any hack or something. Like changing any settings in system plist file etc which would let me do this thing

Comment: That makes no sense. In what world would that (if it existed, which I don’t think it does) be a preferable solution over what I proposed?